# Implementing Google Sign-In via Web-based Authentication in Flutter Android App?

Tags: flutter, google-signin

I'm fairly new to Flutter and I'm currently working on implementing a login page in my app. I want to integrate Google Sign-In functionality but would prefer to use a web-based authentication for Google instead of the native sign-in screens on Android/iOS.

I intend to avoid the users logging into their Gmail accounts on their respective android devices and, instead, have a web-based Google login within the Flutter app as I am ok with user login to there gmail in browser. Could anyone guide me on achieving this or recommend any resources, packages, or methods I could explore to make this happen?

I'd appreciate any help, advice, or pointers you can offer on implementing Google Sign-In using a web-based approach in Flutter I am using Firebase to authenticate the users.
Many thanks for considering my request.

Many thanks for considering my request.

Answer (score 0):

You can use plugin https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth, then integrated with https://console.firebase.google.com and https://console.cloud.google.com

You can search "firebase google authentication flutter" or this video "https://youtu.be/VCrXSFqdsoA?si=vg8jgs9rixEk9bEi"